# How to add Divs dynamically side by side using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

can you please help me how to add Divs side by side dynamically using Jquery.
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idButton').click(function() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            $('body').append('<div id="divId"+'
            i ' style="height:80px;width:80px;background-image:url('
            flashcard1.png ');">Images</div>');
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add it side by side we need `float` css property.

If you give `float:left` It will add side by side. Try with float.

Try like this... And make int to var as xdazz stated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idButton').click(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            $('body').append('<div id="divId"+'
            i ' style="height:80px;width:80px;float:left;background-image:url(\'
            flashcard1.png \');">Images</div>');
        }
    });
});​
```

One more thing after adding float you have to clear it to work the next markup correctly.

Comment: Also, the text inside the append method is not being concatenated properly.  There are two + characters left out.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmcs5/) is a fiddle for you.

Like everyone else said you nead to use the css-attribute `float`.

And also in javaScript variables are declared as `var`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `int` in javascript, should be `var`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
   $('body').append('<div id="divId' + i + '" style="height:80px;width:80px;background-image:url(\'flashcard1.png\');">Images</div>');
}
```

Or

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  $('<div />', {
    id: 'divId' + i,
    style: "height:80px;width:80px;background-image:url('flashcard1.png');"
   }).text('Images').appendTo("body");
}​
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add div css either `float:left` or `float:right`